# MYSQL - SELECT query with LIKE using %% returns incorrect value

Tags: sql, mysql

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE fieldA LIKE '%%' 
  AND fieldB LIKE '%%' 
  AND fieldC LIKE '%%'
```

This returns only records that have all fields completed.  My thought would be that it should return all records in the table.

Does the '%%' actually represent that a value is needed?

**UPDATE1:**

Thanks to some good questions the solution was found:

Query should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE if(fieldA IS NOT NULL,fieldA LIKE '%%',fieldA IS NULL)
  ...
```

Comment: What are example values that it does not bring back? Are they NULLs? If so, then it's perceivable that LIKE only matches those that have strings.

Comment: You are correct Amadiere - if there is one field with a NULL it is not returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LIKE '%%' matches any string, even ones with zero length.  The result of your query is it is returning all rows where the three fields each have a string in them.

My guess is that the fields that are not completed are NULL.  Maybe you should be checking for IS NOT NULL instead of LIKE '%%'?

Comment: Sorry should have clarified more - The LIKE statements are related to a user controllable filter which allows them to search by one or more fields.

Comment: So your example above is the condition in which they select no filters?

Comment: Correct.  Usually at least one field would be partially completed.

Comment: Can you check to see if no filters exist, and if that is true, remove the WHERE clause entirely from the query?

Comment: I could but then if only one field criteria is entered the WHERE criteria will still fail.  I am going to test out using an IF statement to check if the field IS NOT NULL before allowing the criteria to be applied.